# undefined method `sum' for 1:Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sum

```
<% @user.friendships.each do |f| %>
  <%= f.friend.count %>
<% end %>
```

This returns a set of numbers `1 2 1 1 3` but when I tried to get the sum of those values , I get this error: `undefined method sum for 1:Fixnum`.

```
<%= f.friend.count.sum %>
<%= f.friend.count.sum(:value) %>
<%= f.friend.count.inject {|sum, x| sum + x} %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
<%= @user.friendships.inject(0) {|sum, f| sum + f.friend.count} %>
```

The important thing to note is that you're calling inject on the friendships collection and incrementing the sum by f.count.

Comment: `<%= @user.friendships.includes(:friend).inject(0) {|sum, f| sum + f.friend.count} %>` to eager load `friend` associations. This way you're not hitting the database with every iteration.